# Workflow - get transaction Created By Field

Tags: workflow, netsuite

How do I get Created By field of any transaction in workflow. I'm creating a workflow that is applied to Bill record. Bill record is created from PO. I want to send an email to the created by of PO record when Bill gets created.
But I am unable to find that field in workflow.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Refer "Access Purchase Order Fields on Vendor Bills via SuiteFlow"
Suite answer id :37827

Comment: Hi, is it suite answer id: 37827 ?